# Opening RDP File With AutoIT

Tags: autoit

I am new to AutoIT, looking for some help to open RDP file.  RDP files are available in my downloads folder.  Most of the time I don't know my RDP file.   I want to open the most recently downloaded RDP file.  Can someone help me with the code?  For now, I just tried to open RDP file by hardcoding the filename and it worked  PFB the code but I need to find the most recently downloaded RDP file and open the same instead of hardcoding it.

```
Run("explorer.exe " & "C:\Users\Balaji\Downloads")
Run(@Comspec & " /c start " & FileGetShortName('C:\Users\1451615\Downloads\TestRDP.rdp'))
```

Comment: Do you just want your script to look for the latest file you downloaded? Why not download the file with Autoit and then directly start it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this! This should look into your downloads-folder for all files *.rdp and then sort the array, so you get the latest modified file and then Run it.

```
#include <Array.au3>
#include <File.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

;~ Global $downloadPath = 'C:\Users\Balaji\Downloads'
Global $downloadPath = @UserProfileDir & '\Downloads'

Global $rdpFiles = _FileListToArray($downloadPath, '*.rdp', $FLTA_FILES, True)

Global $ar[UBound($rdpFiles)][2]

For $i = 1 To UBound($rdpFiles) - 1
    $ar[$i][0] = $rdpFiles[$i]
    $ar[$i][1] = FileGetTime($rdpFiles[$i], $FT_MODIFIED, $FT_STRING )
Next

_ArraySort($ar, 1, Default, Default, 1)
; _ArrayDisplay($ar) ; If you want to have at look at the array

Run($ar[0], '', @SW_MAXIMIZE)
```